# validationexception message value must point to a valid jre installation in agent installation

Tags: java, continuous-integration

While I am trying to install an agent in IBM UrbanCode Deploy through command line, I am facing a problem like *validationexception message value must point to a valid jre installation in agent installation*. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: In the end we fixed this same issue. It was *either* using a JRE for the wrong arch (i386 versus x64) or using a JRE, where we should have been using a JDK. When we started using a JDK for the correct architecture, this error went away. Not sure which of those two factors fixed it.